# Font weight as a parameter in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to pass font weight as a parameter to a component (SwiftUI View) to then use with `Text`. How can I do this?

I tried to set `weight` as `Weight`, `UIFontDescriptor.TraitKey` (found by searching), but neither work.

E.g.

```swift
let weight: Weight = .bold

init(weight: Weight){
    self.weight = weight
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a pretty quick way to figure out the type.

In a SwiftUI view write something like

```
Text("Hello").fontWeight(.bold)
```

Then <kbd>⌥-click</kbd> on `.bold` and you'll see

[image]

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: use @vadian's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74899339/16370901)!

As soon as I asked the question, I thought of a solution:

Pass the desired weight as a string, e.g. `thin`.

Then use a function when choosing the font:

```swift
.font(.system(size: 22, weight: getWeight(weight: weight), design: .rounded))
```

```swift
func getWeight(weight: String) -> Font.Weight {
    if weight == "thin" {
        return .thin
    }
    return .bold
}
```